# Distorted table with for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table

I'm having troubles with this table. I need that every rows generated by the for loop also generate a new cell (can't upload a screenshot), every for loop iteration generate too much cells that are located on the right side of the table. How can i fix it? Thanks

```
            <?php
                $maxsize = ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
                $firstrow = <<<firstrow
                    <TABLE class="table2" align="center">
                        <TR>
                        <TH scope="row">

                            Puoi caricare massimo 5 file per volta <br> Dimensione massima per file: {$maxsize} 
                        <TD>    
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                <select name="opzioni">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="submit" value="Invio">
                            </form>
                        </TD>
                        </TR>
firstrow;
echo $firstrow;

if (isset($_POST['opzioni'])) {
$openform  = '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileinfo.php" method="POST">' . "\r\n";
$closeform = <<<form
<input type="submit" value="Invio">
</form><br>
form;
$opz       = $_POST['opzioni'];

echo $openform;

for ($i = 0; $i < $opz; $i++) {
echo '<TR>';
    echo '<TH scope="row">';
    echo '<input name="doc' . $i . '" type="file"><br />' . "\r\n";
    echo '<TD rowspan="'.$i.'">';
    echo $closeform;
    echo '</TD>';
echo '</TR>';

}
}

            echo '</TABLE>';
                ?>
```

This is fileinfo.php code

```
<?php

    $max_file_size=ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
$mult=strtolower(substr($max_file_size,strlen($max_file_size)-1));
$val=strtolower(substr($max_file_size,0,strlen($max_file_size)-1));
$max_file_size=$val;
switch($mult){
case 'g':
$max_file_size*=1024;
case 'm':
$max_file_size*=1024;
case 'k':
$max_file_size*=1024;
}

$infotxt = <<<infotxt
    <TABLE class="table1" align="center">
    <TR><th scope="row">Scaricare file .txt contenente le info?<TD><form method="POST">    <input type="submit" value="Download" name="downloadtxt"></form></TD></TR>
    <TR><th scope="row">Ricevere file .txt contenente le info via email?<TD><form method="POST" action="mail.php">Inserisci email <input type="text" name="tomail"><input type="submit" value="Invia Email"></form></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
infotxt;
echo $infotxt.'<br>';


foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v)
{
if (isset($_FILES[$k]) && $_FILES[$k]['error'] == 0) {
$_SESSION['pastepath'] = 'uploads/' .$_FILES[$k]['name'];
if ($_FILES[$k]['size'] > $max_file_size) {
    echo $_FILES[$k]['size'].' &egrave; troppo grande';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['nomefile']     = $_FILES[$k]['name'];
    $_SESSION['size']     = $_FILES[$k]['size'] / 1000;
    $_SESSION['tipo']     = $_FILES[$k]['type'];
    $_SESSION['dataupload']     = date("d/M/Y H:i:s O");
    require_once 'formato.php';
    $_SESSION['descrtipo'] = descmime($_SESSION['tipo']);
    $info      = <<<info
<TABLE class="table1" align="center">
<TR><th scope="row">Nome originale:<TD>{$_SESSION['nomefile']}</TD></TR>
<TR><th scope="row">Dimensione:<TD>{$_SESSION['size']} kB</TD></TR>
<TR><th scope="row">Tipo MIME:<TD>{$_SESSION['tipo']}</TD></TR>
<TR><th scope="row">Data e ora caricamento:<TD>{$_SESSION['dataupload']}</TD></TR>
<TR><th scope="row">Programma da utilizzare:<TD>{$_SESSION['descrtipo']}</TD></TR>
<TR><th scope="row">Rinomina file e scarica<TD><form method="POST">Inserisci il nuovo nome <input type="text" name="newname"><input type="submit" value="Download"></form>  </TD></TR>
</TABLE>
info;
    echo $info.'<br>';


    if (isset($_FILES['tomail']))
    $_SESSION['tomail'] = $_FILES['tomail'];
    if (isset($_FILES['newname']))
    $_SESSION['newname'] = $_FILES['newname'];

} 

}
        else
        echo 'Nessun file caricato';
}
?>
```

Comment: You aren't closing your <TH> tag, and I am unsure why you are even using TH when it should be <TD>foo</TD>.  TR = Table row.  TD = Table Cell.   TH = Table Header Cell.   All tags must be closed.

Comment: I'm using <th> because i used a table template, just need it to make a different style with css

Comment: See my post below.  Using TH isn't an issue, however not on every row.  TH is for the header row.   I have supplied a simple example on how this works.  If you are looking to style the first row on each record, you can see that in my example using td:first-child .

Comment: i've changed the table to show you whtat's my idea. User can choose how many files he will upload. In the snippet i set 3, so the for loop will generate 3 rows and 3 <td> that have to be grouped, in which there will be the submit button. I hope to have explain my idea in a good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of proper table design.

```css
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 250px;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

td:first-child {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

td {
    padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i've changed the table to show you whtat's my idea. User can choose how many files he will upload. In the snippet i set 3, so the for loop will generate 3 rows and 3 <td> that have to be grouped, in which there will be the submit button. I hope to have explain my idea in a good way

Comment: I hate to be "that guy" to ask a question "why don't you use X", but ... why not use a handler like dropzone.js or uploadify, and eliminate the need to the user to painfully choose one file at a time ?

Comment: i've added dropzone.js to my script, but now ca't figure out how to make my fileinfo.php code works. The purpose is to print a table with some info like mime type and which app use to open it for very file uploaded by users

Code is above

Comment: You can use the "success" event to handle a response from the server.  From the PHP script that handles the file upload, you only need to write code as if you are handling a single file upload, dropzone will do a post for each file.  The response from the upload should be in JSON format (as it's easier to handle inside Javascript), and you can put code in that event (javascript) to draw the response into a table